# Best laptop/screen for viewing outdoors?

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I know this might be a little offtopic, but I was wondering if anyone has anything they would recommend.  My current Thinkpad had 220 nits when it was new, but I can't see anything if its bright outside.  My phone (Samsung Nexus S) has 370 nits, but can be hard to see as well.

Specific models or general tips would be great!  Here's to helping ROS move outdoors. :-P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10317/best-laptop/screen-for-viewing-outdoors?/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be looking for a **transreflective display**. As opposed to trying to be brighter than the sun with a backlit display, a transreflective one uses the light emitted onto it. I believe some Sony Vaio or Panasonic laptops have them, but not for cheap.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-06-19**:
Good idea. Just to add: Pixel Qi sells a DIY transreflective display that can replace a traditional netbook's display. I don't have any experience with that, though.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use a [Laptop Compubody Sock](http://sternlab.org/2008/04/body-technology-interfaces/).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4